# Unexpected Token ILLEGAL only in Chrome, only on Refresh

Tags: facebook, wordpress, google-chrome, ssl

Help me Stack Over-flow-nobi, you're my only hope.

I see lots of posts and questions about the 'Unexpected Token ILLEGAL' issue in chrome, but haven't found a solution for my own variety of the problem.

I'm building a Facebook tab that needs to be served https (Facebook policy).  It's a page built in WordPress and I'm using the WordPress HTTPS plugin to force my particular page to render with HTTPS.

When I test with regular old HTTP, everything is fine (except for the "unsecure content" warnings, but that's another issue).

When I test with HTTPS, when the page loads the first time, it's okay, but if I hit REFRESH, then I get the ILLEGAL error.  It's inconsistent - sometimes it balks on a different file, but something bad happens almost every time.

The page is at http://www.facebook.com/pages/TbkCreative-Leavens-VW-Beta/178151292291863?sk=app_363900450303117

[screen shot of error on Chrome console http://tbkcreative.com/sandbox/leavens/files/2012/01/unexpected_token.png](http://tbkcreative.com/sandbox/leavens/files/2012/01/unexpected_token.png)

Any insight?  I'm banging my head against the wall on this one.

Thanks
Trevor

Comment: it looks the issue with your server, is your server working fine? is it serving files normally?

Comment: Can't really test, so just a guess; your javascript files are saved with an UTF-8 BOM (ie byte order mark) at the start and are served with the wrong encoding in the header. If that's the case, just save them as plain text (or UTF-8 without BOM) and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the cooments.  @JoachimIsaksson, if you're on facebook, you should be able to see the issue at the facebook link I included.  The javascript files in question are in the WordPress core, so I'd rather not get into having to edit them, but I will take a look at the encoding.

Comment: @Shaheer, the server does appear to be working fine, except for this issue.  Any ideas on what server config might lead to it?

Comment: @TrevorMills if the server is overloaded ( a lot of requests on it - typically happen with a shared hosting ) then it is going to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

File this one under the red herrings and wild goose chases.

I'm using a plugin called GD Star Rating on this app.  It includes a dynamic CSS file.  It was being loaded in with:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='gdsr_style_main-css'  href='https://tbkcreative.com/sandbox/leavens/wp-content/plugins/gd-star-rating/css/gdsr.css.php?t=1327595625&#038;s=a10i10m20k20c05r05%23121620243046%23121620243240%23s1pchristmas%23s1pcrystal%23s1pdarkness%23s1poxygen%23s1goxygen_gif%23s1pplain%23s1ppumpkin%23s1psoft%23s1pstarrating%23s1pstarscape%23t1pclassical%23t1pstarrating%23t1gstarrating_gif%23lsgflower&#038;o=off&#038;ver=1.9.10' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

If I got rid of all of those query arguments, the problem went away.  Ditto for if I just got rid of the file altogether.  I didn't dig deeper to figure out exactly what was causing the issue, as I was just relieved to figure it out.

I don't understand why this file was causing javascript files down the pipe to be loaded incorrectly.  I don't understand why it only happened in Chrome, accessing the page with HTTPS and when I hit refresh.  Weird.

But fixed.